# "No Access Control Allow Origin" in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, json, http, get

I am trying to develop a website that reads a JSON response from a certain endpoint and post it after certain processing to the page.

I am using $http.get(url) (AngularJS)

However I am facing problems getting the response.
I have tried to use other URLs and it worked then the cause of the problem probably is not the code.

The Error is: "No Access Control Allow Origin header is present on the requested resource".
Other responses suggested something related to CORS and privacy issues ; but when i type the URL directly in my browser it gives a JSON response directly. (So basically there is no privacy issues in the server side right?)

My question is what should I do ? Is there another way to get the content of the page pointed by the url (i am sure that it will only contains the JSON response)

Thanks in Advance

Comment: There's nothing you can do about this, it would need to be fixed by whoever manages *"a certain endpoint"*. The only alternative would be to build your own server-side endpoint that gets the json.

Comment: is it possible to get the problem even though when i type the url of this endpoint in my browser i still get a response ?

Comment: No, you still have to follow the same rules. Requesting it using your browser directly as if it's a web page isn't subject to the same-origin policy.

Comment: Ok Thank you, i think i have understood the cause of the problem. I should contact then the manager of the server side to fix the CORS issue. I am sorry if it was a stupid question but this is my first experience with such issues. Thanks

Comment: Does the request require an auth token given to you by the site you are requesting from? If so, this restriction is to protect you from doing something that would be damaging to both you and them.

Answer (score -1):

I came across this question:
1. If we substitute the URL in the address bar, it is similar to receiving data from the server of this site

2. In order to send requests to other servers need to use **JSONP** HTTPS for secure channel
3. Sending data can be carried out, but with the replies received will be a problem in the form JSON
4. Please send to the server if use PHP, then use **CURL**
5. JS->Our server->Server api->Our server->JS